# Firebase: The database '/google_app_measurement_local.db' is not open

Tags: android, sqlite, firebase, firebase-analytics

After having started using Firebase for event logging in my android app I keep getting these error messages when I fire up my app:

```
E/System: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The database '/...folder here.../google_app_measurement_local.db' is not open.
              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.throwIfNotOpenLocked(SQLiteDatabase.java:2169)
              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.createSession(SQLiteDatabase.java:365)
              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase$1.initialValue(SQLiteDatabase.java:84)
              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase$1.initialValue(SQLiteDatabase.java:83)
              at java.lang.ThreadLocal$Values.getAfterMiss(ThreadLocal.java:430)
              at java.lang.ThreadLocal.get(ThreadLocal.java:65)
              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.getThreadSession(SQLiteDatabase.java:359)
              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.getSession(SQLiteProgram.java:101)
              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.setLastStmt(SQLiteQuery.java:96)
              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.close(SQLiteQuery.java:111)
              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.close(SQLiteCursor.java:300)
              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.finalize(SQLiteCursor.java:366)
              at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:202)
              at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:185)
              at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Here's a snippet from my build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.8.0'
    compile files('src/main/resources/simple-xml-2.7.jar')
    compile files('src/main/resources/date4j.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
    compile files('src/main/resources/picasso-2.5.2.jar')
}
```

All I do is call

```
_firebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(context);
```

and then

```
_firebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SHARE, payload);
```

I have not been able to find any solutions online and am now hoping for help here...

Comment: still exists in 10.0.1

Comment: It appears to be fixed in version `11.0.1.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just faced with this when enabling strictmode, when adding

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.8.0'
```

I had to use earlier version:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.0'
```

I've found latest version from [Firebase Android SDK Release Notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android)

Comment: Although your answer is not an answer as such, changing back to 9.6.0 also works for me. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

Please move to latest version of firebase SDK. Firebase solved this memory leak issue in their updated sdk. Remove your old SDK and add below line in your gradle file.

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.1'
```